# Apache Pdf Box returning number of pages 0 while processing multiple pdfs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdfbox, java-io

My code load multiple pdfs from a folder location and calculate the number of pages. Below code is returning correct page number for many pdfs but for few pdfs it is returning 0. While I am retrying to get the number of pages for those pdfs then the same code is able to calculate the number of pages for those pdfs.

Please find enclosed code which is use for calculating the number of pages:
`

```
public static int getPageCount(Path file) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file.toFile());
        int pageCount = 0;
        try {
            pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();
        } finally {
            document.close();
        }
        return pageCount;
    }
```

`

I want to know the reason why it is not calculating the number of pages for every pdfs.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: Also share the PDF

Comment: Indeed, as the issue occurs only for some pdfs, we need representative examples to analyze.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using apache pdfbox version 2.0.8. And this is happening not for any particular pdf(s). Which pdf(s) is not  returning the number of pages in first go that same pdf is returning the number of pages in second go.
So I don't think this is related to any particular pdf(s).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 
Such as we have total 10000 pdfs for which we need to get the number of pages so I load PDDocument object and get the number of pages one by one. Once the cycle will complete then we get the number of pages for all the pdf(s) except 10 to 20 and while i retry with the same code for those 10 to 20 pdf(s) then it will get the number of pages for remaining pdf(s).

Comment: Why are you using 2.0.8 when the current version is 2.0.27? Do you get the files directly from disk or as a stream from some service?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am getting the files from disk not using any stream.

While this application was developed, that time 2.0.8 was the latest one.

To update the version may resolve the issue???

Comment: Who knows. But if you're using a versioned library, make sure to update it regularly. Unless you work at equifax. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Equifax_data_breach